# how to implements code for receiving a alert message?

Tags: android

hi all how to implements code for displaying alert message that alert message is when system time and our given time is same then it display a message as alert("you have a new message").if our given time is 04:22:00 when system time also same as our given time then receive message as alert.so kindly help any one of you to solve this problem

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking how to know **when** the alert should be shown, or are you asking how to **show** an alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need an `AlarmManager` to wake up the system in the exact moment:

```
long triggerAtTime = 0;
try {
    triggerAtTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
        .parse("2011-07-12 14:00:00").getTime();
} catch (ParseException e) {
}

Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestReceiver.class);
PendingIntent intentToSend = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtTime, intentToSend);
```

And a `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class TestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: notify the user
    }
}
```

And some XML in your manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name=".TestReceiver"></receiver>
```

In the `onReceive` function you can create a `Toast` or a status bar `Notification`:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/index.html